# R: remove data in a logical variable using a factor variable

Tags: r, integer, r-factor

I made the following example code to give you an idea of my real dataset. I have 2 datasets, a factor variable `List` and a logical variable `ok`.

```
df1 <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
df2 <- c("a","d","e")
List <- factor(as.integer(df1 %in% df2))
ok <- c(TRUE,FALSE, FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)
```

The `List` and the `ok` variables has both a length of 7. I want to remove all the samples in `List` with the condition `TRUE` in `ok`. For example: the first, fifth and seventh variables need to be removed in the `List` variable.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easier than you think.

```
List[!ok]
```

Comment: indeed it is much easier than i Thought. Thanks!

Comment: @Lisann: You're welcome.  Don't forget that you can upvote as many answers as you think are useful.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `List[!ok]`? BTW, you don't need `as.logical` as vector `ok` will be saved internaly as `logical`.

Comment: Sorry; edited the question to remove the extraneous `as.logical`.